# Java making a 2D list object of a file of numbers

Tags: java

I have a pyramid of numbers in a file like

- 1
- 2 3

  - 3 4 5

I'm trying to populate a 2D Arraylist with the numbers from a file. I'm trying to populate first a row of numbers then add that row to a column but I can't find the right input test to get that done.

```
ArrayList<Integer> rows = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> columns = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(); 
    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("1.txt"));
        //while (s.hasNext()) {
            String a = s.next();
            String b = s.next();
            s.nextLine();

            while(s.hasNextLine()) {
                while(s.hasNextInt() ) { 
                // I want to say while( has more lines is true )
                // ( create a row of ints and append it to columns
                    rows.add(s.nextInt());

                    }   
                columns.add(rows);
                rows.clear();
            }   

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

edit: my last row being added is  [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5] instead of [3, 4, 5] because the s.hasNextInt() is always true while iterating,
so the while(in.hasNextLine()) only runs once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way of doing it would be to replace the `hasNextLine()` loop with a `nextLine()` and string splitting.

So you'd replace your loop with `nextLine()`

```java
ArrayList<Integer> row;
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> columns = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(); 
try {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("1.txt"));
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] temp = s.nextLine().split(" ");
        row = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(String i : temp) ints.add(Integer.parseInt(i));
        columns.add(row);
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: that's what I ended up doing too. I thought there might be a scanner function or new type input

Comment: Indeed. I was not sure what version of Java you were using, so I didn't suggest the [Files.readAllLines()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) API, but that is also worth looking into if you know your file isn't going to be too big.

Answer (score 1):

At a quick glance, I'll say that this line here is your problem: `rows.clear();`

Your `rows` variable is still pointing to the same list it was pointing to before you added it to `columns` so if you clear it, then all you've done is add an empty `ArrayList` to `columns`.

Replace this line:

```
rows.clear();
```

With this:

```
rows = new ArrayList<>();
```

That way, the `rows` variable is still pointing to an empty, brand new `ArrayList`, but the `ArrayList` it was pointing to before is left alone.

Comment: it doesn't change my output, the last row is [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5] instead of [3, 4, 5] I should have added that to the question. my s.hasNextLine() only runs once